# Why does the first scroll action in some windows get ignored?

Tags: scrolling

Whenever I move my cursor out of and into a window, the next scroll event gets ignored. This happens for (for example) Google Chrome, gnome-terminal, gnome-system-monitor and Slack, but not in Firefox, frescobaldi or Steam. How can I stop this happening?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with the Unity desktop.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean by "scroll event"? Are you using the mouse wheel, keyboard arrows, click and grab the scrollbar, all of the above, ect?

Comment: @Jeff Mouse wheel, sorry I wasn't clear.